# can not send file with Axios to django, It's always empty

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, axios

I'm using **axios** and **django 3.1.6**, the problem is that all axios can not send files via **post request** and in my **views** `request.FILES` is always empty. (while sending it as default html form post, it's not empty)

I'm doing it like this
my `script.js` file

```
...
$("#myform").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
$("button[type='submit']").click(function() {
  let form = $("#myform").serialize()
  axios.post(".", form).then((response) => {
    if (response.data.status == "success") {
      myform.reset();
      // other codes here
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  })
});
```

`template.html`

```
...
<form method="post", action="." enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="myform">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- inputs .. file inputs -->
</form>
```

`view.py`

```
if request.POST.get("add-medical-record"):
  print(request.POST) # i have my data here
  print(request.FILES) # it's always empty
  ...
```

thanks you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it the problem was in `script.js` file. just send it as `new FormData(myform)` and that's all. it works.

finally my `script.js` file

```
...
$("#myform").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
$("button[type='submit']").click(function() {
  let form = new FormData($("#myform")[0])
  axios.post(".", form).then((response) => {
    if (response.data.status == "success") {
      myform.reset();
      // other codes here
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  })
});
```